# A single elimination tournament - number of possible combinations

Tags: math, probability, combinatorics

What are the number of combinations in which 8 persons taking part in a single elimination tornament play? Total no of matches played would be 7 but I also need the number of combinations that can for this set

Comment: You must clarify if you want to measure the number of possible fixtures (which is essentially the number of binary trees with 7 nodes of degree 3) or also the number of possible outcomes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't involve programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't matter where in the tree a player starts, but only which opponents he/she fights, and how long he/she gets, we can say that the left player always wins and then just calculate the number of ways to create the bottom most row, which is 8! 40320.

The first possibility:

```
       a
   a       e
 a   c   e   g
a b c d e f g h
```

The second possibility:

```
       a
   a       e
 a   c   e   h
a b c d e f h g
```

Comment: Actually this also requires, that you care about two people fight. Otherwise you could swap b and d and so on.

Answer (score 3):

There are (8 * 7) / 2 combinations = 28
[ in other words, 8!/(2! * (8-2)!) ]

With Set::Partition in Perl I can write:

```
my $s = Set::Partition->new(
    list      => ['a'..'h'],
    partition => [2, 6],
);

while (my $p = $s->next) {
    print join( ' ', map { "[@$_]" } @$p ), $/;
}
```

which gives

```
[a b] [c d e f g h]
[a c] [b d e f g h]
[a d] [b c e f g h]
[a e] [b c d f g h]
[a f] [b c d e g h]
[a g] [b c d e f h]
[a h] [b c d e f g]
[b c] [a d e f g h]
[b d] [a c e f g h]
[b e] [a c d f g h]
[b f] [a c d e g h]
[b g] [a c d e f h]
[b h] [a c d e f g]
[c d] [a b e f g h]
[c e] [a b d f g h]
[c f] [a b d e g h]
[c g] [a b d e f h]
[c h] [a b d e f g]
[d e] [a b c f g h]
[d f] [a b c e g h]
[d g] [a b c e f h]
[d h] [a b c e f g]
[e f] [a b c d g h]
[e g] [a b c d f h]
[e h] [a b c d f g]
[f g] [a b c d e h]
[f h] [a b c d e g]
[g h] [a b c d e f]
```

which you can interpret two players playing, and the six others standing around cheering and drinking beer.

Comment: How did you get from `(8 * 7) / 2` to that partitioning?

Comment: by partitioning a set of 8 elements into a set of 2 (the players) and a set of 6 (the non-players).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, how many possible 2 player matches are there in a pool of 8 players then the answer is 28 (8x7/2).  If you mean something else, then clarify your question a bit.