# Ways to create unique single elimination brackets

Tags: python, math, combinatorics

I'm looking for a method to create all possible unique starting positions for a N-player (N is a power of 2) single elimination (knockout) bracket tournament.

Lets say we have players 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D' and want to find out all possible initial positions. The tournament would then look tike this:
A vs B, C vs D. Then winner(AB) vs winner(CD).

(I will use the notation (A,B,C,D) for the setup above)

Those would simply be all possible permutations of 4 elements, there are 4!=24 of those, and it's easy to generate them.

But they wouldn't be unique for the Tournament, since

(A,B,C,D), (B,A,C,D), (B,A,D,C), (C,D,A,B), ...

would all lead to the same matches being played.

In this case, the set of unique setups is, I think:

(A,B,C,D), (A,C,B,D), (A,D,C,B)

All other combinations would be "symmetric".

Now my questions would be for the general case of N=2^d players:

- how many such unique setups are there?
- is this a known problem I could look up? Haven't found it yet.
- is there a method to generate them all?
- how would this method look in python

(questions ranked by perceived usefulness)

I have stumpled upon [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244009/a-single-elimination-tournament-number-of-possible-combinations), but it does not really deal with the problem I'm discussing here.

Comment: I think you want [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), rather than `permutations` - you can get all pairs, then pair those to get the first round matchups.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Won't that give you 4 C 2 == 6, though? Where are the other 3 combinations that the OP missed?

Comment: @PatrickCollins it gives you six pairs of teams, then you pair those pairs (first to last, second to penultimate, etc.) to get the first rounds `[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]` -> `[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'D', 'B', 'C')]`. Obviously this gets more complex as `n` increases.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, you're right.

Comment: That works well for N=4, but how to generalise it? For N=8 there would be 8*7/2=28 pairs, but how do I proceed from there?

Comment: I would do that backwards. Imagine the finals. There is a set of players that can access it from the first tree and another set from the second tree. You need to go over all of those sets (you can have the first set lexicographically smaller than the second).

Answer (score 1):

> how many such unique setups are there?

Let there be n teams. There are n! ways to list them in order. We'll start with that. Then deal with the over-counting.

Say we have 8 teams. One possibility is

ABCDEFGH

Swapping teams 1 and 2 won't make a difference. We can have

BACDEFGH

and the same teams play.Divide by 2 to account for that. Swapping 3 and 4 won't either. Divide by 2 again. Same with teams 5 and 6. Total there are 4 groups of 2 (4 matches in the first round). So we take n!, and divide by 2^(n/2).

But here is the thing. We can have order

CDABEFGH

In this example, we are swapping the first two with third and fourth. CDABEFGH is indistinguishable from ABCDEFGH for the purpose of this. So here, we can divide by 2^(n/4).

The same can happen over and over again. At the end, the total number of starting positions should be n!/(2^(n-1)).

We can also think of it a bit different. If we look at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2269581/revisions, we can also think of it as a tree.

```
       a         b (runner up)
   a       e
 a   c   e   h
a b c d e f h g
```

Here there are 8! ways for us to arrange all the letters at the base, determining one way for the bracket to work out. If we are looking at the starting position, it doesn't matter who won. There were a total of 7 games (and each of the games could have turned out differently), so we divide by 2^7 to account for that over counting.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense. I was already trying to build a 'filter' for the full list of permutations using this, but I never actually did the math w.r.t. number of unique setups. I'm still trying to think of a way to generate this list without generating all permutations and then filtering.

Comment: Are there 315 "different" starting positions for 8 teams? I find 105 since you can choose (8 C 4)/2 (ie 35) for the finals and then (4 C 2)/2 (ie 3) for the semi-finals. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to work backwards? The way I'm looking at it disregards who wins. In ABCDEFGH is the same as BACDEFGH to be, because it doesn't matter which one goes ahead. Think of it more of a tree, except you are swapping branches since it doesn't matter who is on the left.

Comment: That's exactly how I think this. There are 70 ways to choose people from the main left subtree, 35 unique ways by taking into account the symmetry. Now consider the main left subtree. You have 6 ways to choose the (2) people on its left (sub)subtree. 3 unique ways by taking into account the symmetry. That's the reason why I count 35*3=105 unique starting positions.

Comment: Ok I get it, 35*3*3=315